# Read only configuration on the actuator's "logging" endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to enable the actuator's "logging" endpoint on a production environment. If I can use it on the production environment, I can check the logging configuration on the Spring-Boot-Admin server.

But if I enable it, LoggersEndpoint accepts configuration overwrite request. When it's rewritable, it causes the security issue.

Is there any way to deny "@WriteEndpoint" request on the "loging" endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to secure your endpoints by spring security otherwise,the only option is to **disable the logger endpoint** like below.

```
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=false
```